# Abelian sandpile models

Tags: pr.probability, sandpile, graph-theory

This question is about a popular probabilistic model on graphs studied in physics, mostly, for the standard lattice in ${\mathbb R}^n$ but also on other graphs (this model is of the same spirit as percolation, Ising model, etc.).

Consider an infinite $d$-regular transitive rooted graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$ and represent it as an increasing union of finite rooted graphs $\Gamma_k$. For each $k$ consider the standard [Abelian sandpile model](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.130.7873&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on $\Gamma_k$ (with a sink vertex added as usual). Let $b(k)$ be the number of  recurrent configurations on $\Gamma_k$, $a(k,n)$ be the number of recurrent configurations such that adding a piece of sand at the root causes an avalanche that involves toppling of $n$ vertices in $\Gamma_k$ (all terminology can be found in the paper above). For every $n$ let $p(n,k)= a(k,n)/b(k)$.

**Question 1.**  Does the limit $p(n)=\lim_{k\to \infty} p(n,k)$ exist?

**Question 2.**  Does the limit (limsup or liminf) depend essentially on the sequence $\Gamma_k$? For example, is it true that any two functions $p(n)$ of $\Gamma$ corresponding to different $(\Gamma_k)$ and $(\Gamma_k')$ have the same growth?

I suspect that physicists who study these models would say that the answer to both questions is obviously "yes".  But I have not seen a formal proof. Still the literature is large so I might have missed something.

Comment: How can the answer to "Why does the limit exist?" be "(obviously) yes"?  Did you mean to ask "Does the limit exist?"?

Comment: @Noam: Of course you are right. I'll fix the question.

Comment: There are situations when the sandpile groups of $\Gamma_k$'s form an inverse system (e.g. when $\Gamma_k$ are binary de Bruijn digraphs, for which Lionel Levine actually computed these groups (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/directed-line.pdf), the homomorphisms are just taking $2^{i-j}$ powers ). 

IMHO the corresponding profinite group ought to be connected with $\Gamma$ – perhaps it's the right way to define its sandpile group? Perhaps this might help to understand the question asked :-)

Comment: @Dima: Do these groups always form an inverse system? In that case a weaker question would indeed be whether the inverse limit does not depend on the sequence of subgraphs. Anyway, the question was related to my student's paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1110.6263. I just asked him to define the sandpile model not for an infinite graph but for a sequence of finite graphs converging to an infinite graph. This way there is not ambiguity. 

Comment: @Mark: these de Bruijn digraphs, they do form an inverse system. In the general setting of L.Levine's paper, probably, too, it is true... 
I guess I know what the inverse limit in the de Bruijn digraphs case looks like, but have no clue how to confirm this. Neither I know if this limit can be realized as the sandpile group; I should look at the article of your student.

Comment: @Mark: meant: "*the sandpile groups of* these de Bruijn digraphs..."

Comment: @Dima: I do not know if sandpile groups of infinite graphs can be defined. Even "recurrent configurations" are not obviously define. So the inverse limit of the sandpile groups of finite subgraphs should be considered a definition of the sandpile group of the infinite graph. Then the  question of uniqueness becomes even more important. 

Comment: @Mark, at least, if your infinite graph is a directed tree, with each vertex of finite degree, (I guess a DAG would work, I didn't check the details though-for finite DAGs it's OK) then the monoid of stable configurations is a group (which must coincide with the sandpile group), with the all-0 configuration as neutral element. Let $S$ be a stable configuration.
If $x$ is a minimal vertex on which $S$ has a chip, i.e. $S(x)>0$, then $S^{-1}(x)=deg(x)-S(x)+1$, and $S^{-1}(y)=deg(y)-S(y)$ for each $y$ in the subtree rooted at $x$. In $S+S^{-1}$ all such $x$ can be fired, getting 0 in the limit.